# Finding out who can ssh into a certain account without typing a password (Debian)

Tags: debian, ssh, configuration

Is there a way that I can find out what users have permission to ssh into a certain account without typing a password? Lets say that I have three users: alice, bob, and john. Is there a way to see if bob is allowed to ssh into alice without a password? ~/.ssh/authorized_keys does not exist on any of the user accounts.

Answer (score 2):

no - anyone who has the private key(s) which are authorized can do this, and there's no way to see who has it until they use it (after all, the key could be on a machine which you cannot inspect).